# How to match Simulated Data to Experimental Data of a Battery in Python by estimating/adjusting parameters(R0,R1,R2,C1,C2)

Tags: python, optimization, battery, gekko

I am currently working on parameter optimizing of a battery using Python. I have an experimental data and the data from simulation of a battery in Python. My task is to adjust battery parameters in such a way that; the simulated data should fit with the experimental data.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FVY66.png)

The equation for the simulated data is: `Voltage = Vocv-R0It-R1It*exp(-t/R1C1)-R2It*exp(-t/R2C2)` where, R0,R1,R2,C1,C2 needs to be adjusted/estimated.

I have the value for Vocv, It and t.

I have taken the initial value of `R0=0.0000001, R1= 0.0000001, R2=0.0000001, C1= 3e-07, C2=3e-07`

As, the dataframe is huge; I am gonna give a sample for these values.

```
Vocv = [4.19856,4.19856,4.19855,4.19855,4.19855,4.19854,4.19854,4.19853,4.19853,4.19852,4.19852]
t=     [10.8648,10.8855,10.906,10.926,10.9467,10.9671,10.9872,11.0079,11.0272,11.0473,11.0679]
It=    [299688,299689,299697,299703,299693,299695,299688,299696,299695,299691,299694]
Vmeas= [4.1265,4.12649,4.12649,4.12648,4.12648,4.12647,4.12647,4.12646,4.126,4.12646,4.12645]
```

And the sample for Experimental data is below:

```
Vmeas2=[4.152166666666667,4.151833333333333,4.1505,4.1495,4.151666666666666,4.149,4.149166666666667,4.1495,4.153333333333333,4.150333333333333,4.150833333333333]
Time2 = [32.5958,32.6559,32.7161,32.7762,32.8363,32.8965,32.9566,33.0167,33.0769,33.137,33.1972]
```

I am very new to programming, please suggest how to solve this using `GEKKO` or any other optimizer.

**EDIT:** The code that I have tried after the suggestion:
As, my prime goal is `Vmeas=Vmeas2` by adjusting/estimating R0-R2,C1&C2.

```
Voltage = m.CV(Vmeas2); Voltage.FSTATUS = 1
Vocv = m.Param(Vocv); t = m.Param(t); It = m.Param(It)
R0,R1,R2 = m.Array(m.FV,3,value=1e-7,lb=1e-8, ub=1e-15)
C1,C2 = m.Array(m.FV,2,value=3e-7,lb=1e-8, ub=3e-15)
R0.STATUS=1; R1.STATUS=1; R2.STATUS=2
C1.STATUS=1; C2.STATUS=1
Time2 = m.Param(Time2)
#t.value = Time2

m.Equation(Voltage==Vocv-R0*It \
                        -R1*It*m.exp(-(t/R1)*C1) \
                        -R2*It*m.exp(-(t/R2)*C2))
#t.value = Time2
m.options.IMODE = 2
m.solve(disp=False)

plt.subplot(2,1,2)
plt.title('Experimental')
plt.plot(Voltage.value,'bo',label='Predicted')
plt.plot(Vmeas2,'rx',label='Measured')
plt.legend(); plt.ylabel('Value')
plt.show()
print('R0: ' + str(R0.value[0]))
print('R1: ' + str(R1.value[0]))
print('R2: ' + str(R2.value[0]))
print('C1: ' + str(C1.value[0]))
print('C2: ' + str(C2.value[0]))
```

However, the unwanted error is coming:

```
line 71, in <module>
    m.solve(disp=False)

  File "/gekko/gekko.py", line 2227, in solve
    self.load_JSON()

  File "/gekko/gk_post_solve.py", line 50, in load_JSON
    vp.__dict__[o] = data[vp.name][o]

KeyError: 'p12'
```

Answer (score 0):

Gekko has a mode (`IMODE=2`) for [regression to fit experimental data](https://gekko.readthedocs.io/en/latest/imode.html). There is more information on parameter regression with a [nonlinear regression example application](https://apmonitor.com/me575/index.php/Main/NonlinearRegression). Here is a solution with the reduced data set that you provided.

[image: regression fit]

```py
from gekko import GEKKO

# fit parameters
m = GEKKO(remote=False)
Vocv = [4.19856,4.19856,4.19855,4.19855,4.19855,4.19854,\
        4.19854,4.19853,4.19853,4.19852,4.19852]
t=     [10.8648,10.8855,10.906,10.926,10.9467,10.9671,\
        10.9872,11.0079,11.0272,11.0473,11.0679]
It=    [299688,299689,299697,299703,299693,299695,\
        299688,299696,299695,299691,299694]
Vmeas= [4.1265,4.12649,4.12649,4.12648,4.12648,4.12647,\
        4.12647,4.12646,4.126,4.12646,4.12645]
Voltage = m.CV(Vmeas); Voltage.FSTATUS = 1
Vocv = m.Param(Vocv); t = m.Param(t); It = m.Param(It)
R0,R1,R2 = m.Array(m.FV,3,value=1e-7,lb=1e-8)
C1,C2 = m.Array(m.FV,2,value=3e-7,lb=1e-8)
R0.STATUS=1; R1.STATUS=1; R2.STATUS=2
C1.STATUS=1; C2.STATUS=1
m.Equation(Voltage==Vocv-R0*It \
                        -R1*It*m.exp(-(t/R1)*C1) \
                        -R2*It*m.exp(-(t/R2)*C2))
m.options.IMODE = 2
m.solve(disp=False)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.figure(1,figsize=(8,6))
plt.subplot(2,1,1)
plt.title('Fit')
plt.plot(Voltage.value,'bo',label='Predicted')
plt.plot(Vmeas,'rx',label='Measured')
plt.legend(); plt.ylabel('Value')
plt.ylim([min(Vmeas)-0.01,max(Vmeas)+0.01])

print('R0: ' + str(R0.value[0]))
print('R1: ' + str(R1.value[0]))
print('R2: ' + str(R2.value[0]))
print('C1: ' + str(C1.value[0]))
print('C2: ' + str(C2.value[0]))

# test fit on experimental data, if different length than fitting
#  then create a new model with the same variables and equations but
#  use the values for R0-R2 and C1,C2.
Vmeas2= [4.152166666666667,4.151833333333333,4.1505,\
         4.1495,4.151666666666666,4.149,4.149166666666667,\
         4.1495,4.153333333333333,4.150333333333333,\
         4.150833333333333]
Time2 = [32.5958,32.6559,32.7161,32.7762,32.8363,32.8965,\
        32.9566,33.0167,33.0769,33.137,33.1972]
t.value = Time2
m.options.IMODE = 2
m.solve(disp=False)

plt.subplot(2,1,2)
plt.title('Experimental')
plt.plot(Voltage.value,'bo',label='Predicted')
plt.plot(Vmeas2,'rx',label='Measured')
plt.legend(); plt.ylabel('Value')
plt.show()
```

Perhaps more data produces a better fit.

Comment: Thank you sir for replying. I am trying to fit experimental data as you suggested however, getting some unwanted error. **Code:** `Voltage = m.CV(Vmeas2); Voltage.FSTATUS = 1` **Error:** `line 62, in <module>
    m.solve(disp=False)`  `line 2227, in solve
    self.load_JSON()`   `line 70, in load_JSON
    vp.__dict__[o] = data[vp.name][o]`  `KeyError: 'v2'`

Comment: I did try it in other way, the code I have edited above however, also getting some unwanted error. I am unable to understand where it is going wrong. I would be grateful for your help.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to redefine Voltage once it is already declared. If you want to test on different experimental results then try making a new model with `m2 = GEKKO()` and repeat the equations with `m2.Equation()`, `m2.Array()`, etc., but use the values from the fitting.

Comment: If you are still getting an error after trying that then please create a new question with your code.

Comment: I have created a new issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68116432/getting-error-while-fitting-simulated-data-and-experimental-data-of-a-battery-in